# Hyperplane : Show equality of sets

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $1\leq n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p\neq q\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $v:=q-p$ and $m:=\frac{1}{2}(p+q)$.

Let $H_{p,q}:=\left \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid d(p,x)=d(q,x)\right \}$.

Show that $H_{p,q}=m+v^{\perp }$.

It holds that $v^{\perp }=\{x\in V\mid v\cdot x=0_{\mathbb{R}}\}$.

Let $y\in H_{p,q}$. Then it holds that $d(p,y)=d(q,y)$. So we get that $\|p-y\|=\|q-y\|$, i.e. $(p-y)\cdot (p-y)=(q-y)\cdot (q-y)$.

How do we get from here that $y$ is of contained in  $m+v^{\perp }$ ? Do we have to solve at the equation $(p-y)\cdot (p-y)=(q-y)\cdot (q-y)$ for $y$ ?

Comment: Calculate $(y - m) \cdot v$ and hope you get $0$.

Comment: Ahh ok!! Thank you for the hint!! :-) For the other direction we suppose that $y\in m+v^{\perp }$. Then wehave that $(y-m)\cdot v=0$. How do we get then that $y\in H_{p,q}$ ? @themathandlanguagetutor

Comment: If you showed $(y - m) \cdot v = 0$ by showing that $(y - m) \cdot v = \frac{1}{2} (d(p, y)^2 - d(q, y)^2)$, then you can just reverse the argument.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!! :-) @themathandlanguagetutor